# How to find values in one column in another column with multiple values

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, vlookup

I have an excel like

```
A            B      START DATE     END DATE
1            10     01-jan-2016   02-jan-2016
2            11     01- jan-2051   02-feb-2061
3            1      04-mar-2016    07-mar-2016
4            1      08-mar-2016    10-mar-2016  
5            5      01-mar-2016    03-dec-2016
6            5      03-nov-2016    31-dec-4712
```

I am new to excel. I want to highlight or extract the columns in A column which can be found in B Column along with the start date and end date .

That is result should be like :

```
            A      start_date     end_date
            1      04-mar-2016    07-mar-2016
            1      08-mar-2016    10-mar-2016  
            5      01-mar-2016    03-dec-2016
            5      03-nov-2016    31-dec-4712
```

Can anyone pls suggest something ?

Comment: does the A column contain the filter of B... and b to d is the data table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **E2** enter:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,B2)>0,"X","")
```

and copy down.  Then filter the table

[image]

You can hide any un-wanted columns after that.

Comment: i like the solution...  i would change the countif to match, because in a very long list if the a column is sorted then binaric search is quicker than log (n)

Comment: @Asaf  I agree with you.

Comment: Just to add to this, I understand that MATCH(item,range,0) does a linear search and an exact match but MATCH(item,range,1) does a binary search but doesn't do an exact match: so you'd have to use the second form of MATCH then check for equality as discussed here http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/match-exact-vs-binary.htm

Comment: @tom..even a non liniar match can be more efficient... once the value is found she search is over the the average search is log(n/2)